# Are there any "penalties" for defining a struct inside a function?

Tags: c++, c, function, struct

Just out of curiosity..

As the titles says: **are there any "penalties" for defining a struct inside a function?** (like *performance, memory, bad programming practice*, etc.)

---

P.S. I know, that it's a common practice to define (NON-template) functors inside functions, but still..)

Comment: The only "penalty" I can think of, is that the structure instances of it can't be referenced from outside of the function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - of course, I have this in mind. It could be an advantage, not "penalty", depending on the situation.

Comment: No probs, just asking, I didn't directed my comment to you :)

Comment: If anything, there *could* be a slight performance increase, but only if the compiler is really smart.  I can imagine scenarios where the compiler might find ways to optimize away variables inside a struct if its scope is limited to a function.  However, that would break other struct rules/conventions, so who knows.  Just a crazy thought.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In C++11, no - there's no penalty. I would even consider it a very good style to not pollute any "more visible" scopes with you implementation details, unless, of course, you want to reuse that functor elsewhere. However, **lambdas** are essentially a condensed form of this idea, and **should usually be preferred** if you are just using the struct as functor. For all kinds of data, it is perfectly fine, although it usually competes with `std::pair` and `std::tuple` in that aspect.

In C++03, you cannot use such a struct as a template parameter, since those parameters need to have external linkage (Visual Studio lets you do it anyways, though). It can still be useful to use such a struct with a polymorphic interface.

Comment: Does this mean, that in C++11, template parameters are allowed?

Comment: I disagree with preferring lambdas over functors. Using a functor helps compiler do inlining optimization thus avoiding unnecessary function call overhead. However using a lambda will force a function call every time similar to using a function pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Since it's purely a visibility issue, I can't imagine a plausible scenario where there would be a performance or memory penalty.

Comment: I think the author was referring to "bad programming practices" in general when he wrote "bad style" ... Maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++03, then technically you can't use a locally defined structure as a template argument but some compilers (namely MSVC) allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about performance, but I was wondering about another issue. Are you asking for both C and C++ or just one of those languages? I am taking a wild guess that you want to define a structure in a function for purposes of scope or hiding the structure.

For C, you can approach hiding things by defining and declaring structures in a separate module and making them static. Then, you can provide access functions, much as you would for members of a C++ class. You would include function declarations in a .h file for those modules that needed to access the structures.

If this is for C++, then creating a class and making the structure private or protected along with your writing the appropriate get/set/manipulate methods takes care of the rest.

If you edited your original post and expanded why you're asking this, you've asked a good question.

Comment: I'm asking for both - C and C++, as I said, it's just out of curiosity, as I did this several times these days (struct inside function). Thanks for giving me some alternatives, I know about them and I was just wondering about this exact case - should I avoid such things or not. 
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a locally defined structure for making an object of a templated type if some member functions are not invocable based on compile time constraints.

Example:

```
template<typename T>
concept C = requires(T t) { { t.unsupported() }; };

template <typename T>
struct X {
    void unsupported() { static_assert(std::is_void_v<T>); }
};
static_assert(C<X<int>>);

template <typename T>
C auto make()
{
    struct Y {
        void unsupported() { static_assert(std::is_void_v<T>); }
    };
    return Y{};
}

int main()
{
    C auto x = X<int>{};      // compiles fine
    C auto y = make<int>();   // error: static assertion failed
    return 0;
}
```